# How to properly pass variables to apollo useQuery?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

So I need a pair of fresh eyes to help me out! I just started using the new hooks for apollo and they are pretty cool! However, I am running into an issue when I try to pass variables, it returns undefined.

I have this query in a graphql server which hits a rest API but at the moment I just have returning scalar JSON

```js
fetchRecipes(calories: String!, meal: String!): JSON
```

in my component:

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_RECIPES, {
    variables: { calories: 500, meal: "beef" }
  });
```

```
const FETCH_RECIPES = gql`
  query FetchRecipes($calories: String, $meal: String) {
    fetchRecipes(calories: $calories, meal: $meal)
  }
`;
```

when I `console.log(data)` it returns `undefined`,

however, why does this work? (not passing the variables through `useQuery`)

```
  query {
    fetchRecipes(calories: "500", meal: "beef")
  }
```

This is what the component looks like:

```
const Recipes = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_RECIPES, {
    variables: { calories: "500", meal: "beef" }
  });

  if (loading) return <Loading>Loading...</Loading>;
  if (error) return <Error>Data couldn't be fetched</Error>;

  return (
    <RecipeContext.Consumer>
      {({ suggestedCaloricIntake }) => (
        <View>
          <Text>Suggested: {suggestedCaloricIntake}</Text>

          <Picture
            style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}
            source={{ uri: data.fetchRecipes.hits[0].recipe.image }}
            accessibilityLabel='meal image'
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </RecipeContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Has the async function completed already when you do the logging?

Comment: @Markus thanks for replying :)! Yea, I updated the question to contain the component's code. It hits the error conditional and returns a generic error message. When I hard code the variables directly into the query it returns some data

Comment: Calories should be a string

Comment: @DanielRearden sorry, that was a typo on stackoverflow, I have it as a string on my editor

Comment: What I also noted, that the String Type is in the templated const Query withouth the ! (non null), but in your Schema it is with the !.  Looking at the apollo docs, in their example both match. Maybe this makes a difference?

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue is that you give `calories: 500` as an integer into the query but you told with `calories: String!` that you only accept a **String** with the `!`

EDIT:
Remove the `!` if the API accept it, otherwise change the input Value to "500"
e.g

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_RECIPES, {
    variables: { calories: "500", meal: "beef" }
  });
```